# Saving pointer to memory pointed by a void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, void

Consider the following situation.

I have a `void * first` pointing to a certain amount of memory. I have another `void * second` pointing to something else. I want to save `void * second` in the memory pointed by the first pointer.
[image]

My approach:

`*(void**) first = second;`

Is this valid? Are there any precautions to consider?

Comment: Do you want to copy data from second area to first one?

Comment: nope, it doesn't do that. Most probably you want `memcpy(first, second, the_size);`.

Comment: I want the address of the second area to be stored in the first area.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Though I'd agree that `memcpy` is probably a better idea here, I don't quite understand what you mean with "it doesn't do that". Consider `using T = void*; T m; T* pm = &m; void* first = pm; *((T*)first) = second;`

Comment: This is a bit weird, to be honest i don't get why you'd want to do that.  You should probably use `static_cast` rather than a C-style cast, but that works too, also make sure that you're accessing well aligned memory (for instance, if you allocated 9 bytes from `std::malloc` whose address is stored in `p`, you can't safely store a `void*` at address `p+1`).

Comment: I'd add that i don't see pointers to void often in C++, and that it's usually advisable to avoid them as it's a good way to cause undefined behaviours, though. But if you really need them and know what you're doing go ahead. Just make sure that you reallly do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write anything you want to the memory location pointed by `void*` as long as:

- It is large enough to hold that data type
- It is sufficiently aligned for data type
- Reads from that location consistent with writes

So, it's legal to do things like:

```
void* first = malloc(sizeof(void*));
*(void**)first = second;
....
void* another = *(void**)first; //Now another == second
```

But anything else, for example:

- `malloc(sizeof(int*))`, or `malloc(4)`
- `void* first = &someCharArray[11]`
- `int* another = *(int**)first`

Is implementation defined at best. And sometimes undefined behavior.

That is exactly what `void*` type for - you cast some pointer to `void*`, then you cast back. You are responsible for types to match.

Comment: @JensMunk It seems StackOverflow's comment formatting has had an unfortuante effect on your expression, in particular on the `*` characters. Enclose in backticks `\`` to avoid interpretation of `*italic text*` as *italic text*.

Comment: @dyp Thanks, I will remember this `*(void**) first = second;` is perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int memory[10];
    void *first = ( void * )memory;
    void *second = ( void * )&memory[5];

    *( int * )first = ( int )second;

    return 0;
}
```

You can validate result in memory[0]